# Touch screen: Register touch event when finger glides into element

Tags: touchscreen, touch-event

I want to register anytime a user touches a certain "button" element. This can, for example, be by tapping it or by putting a finger down on it or by putting a finger down outside the element and then gliding into it. This element needs to be more sensitive than an actual form button.

I register the first two with touchstart:

```
$("id=button]").live('touchstart', function() {...})
```

But nothing seems to register the gliding-into-the-element motion. I have tried touchmove and touchenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of listening for events on the specific element, I ended up listening for touch events on the whole body and then checking whether the touch coordinates are within the element's coordinates.